# How to check that the value of column in particular row is not null and is also tab delimeted

Tags: java, csv, io

I am parsing a .csv file that is tab delimited. As you can see, there are arrows in place of the tabs; this is because I have enabled the "Show all characters" option in my notepad.

```
AAA->BBB->CCC->CRLF

agf->jui->kje->aweCRLF

bvg->qaz->plm->yhbCRLF
```

Now I am am using csv beans 0.7 parser to parse this .csv file and I am getting the objecTS for each columns like this

```
if(f.getAAA() && f.getBBB() && f.getCCC() && f.getDDD()) // IT IS GETTING THE VALUE OF ROW1 agfjuikjeawe
  { }
```

Now as this .csv file is received from backend, it's possible that the value of any column could also be null, as shown below

```
AAA->BBB->CCC->CRLF

agf->->kje->aweCRLF

bvg->qaz->plm->yhbCRLF
```

I am putting a condition like this to check for null values, but, as you can see, if the value is not there but tab is, then my condition to check this is correct

```
if(f.getAAA()!=null && f.getBBB()!=null && f.getCCC()!=null && f.getDDD()!=null)
  { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library you're using, but with plain java you could use the [split(string)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method of String in each of the lines of the csv file as this:

```
final String s = "abc\tefg\thij";
final String [] values = s.split("\t");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
```

**EDIT:** Where the "\t" argument of the method is the special character of the tab. Then, you could check the elements in the array to look for an empty string, that would be your null value.